# Is there an updated list of bakers accepting delegation?

Tags: baking, delegating

I plan to delegate my coins, as I cannot afford to keep a node (PC on all the time, monitoring for not being deactivated, etc). Is there an updated, perhaps official list of bakers around? Googling I can see many websites (e.g. Staked, Tezos Tacos, Tezwhale, etc) but there seems not to be a centralised, comprehensive, reliable list of bakers around.

Any one know one? If there is not such a resource, it would be great if the Tezos foundation or the official website maintains such a list.

Answer (score 8):

We also maintain a list of bakers on tzscan :

https://tzscan.io/delegation-services

When you click on the baker you’ll get all the information that you will need.

Answer (score 3):

To compare performance of different bakers, a good site is also: https://bakendorse.com/#/bakers-rankings (although still in beta)

And if you want to check if your selected baker correctly pays out the rewards as stated by them, you can do so at https://baking-bad.org

Answer (score 1):

https://mytezosbaker.com is a reliable well maintained list. There is no official list as with anything related to Tezos

Answer (score 0):

https://mytezosbaker.com/

https://tzscan.io/delegation-services

http://coinfunda.com/5-best-tezos-bakers-to-delegate-xtz-tokens-for-baking/

Discussion on Reddit here: https://www.reddit.com/r/tezos/comments/9x6gop/tezos_bakers_list/

Comment: please expand your answer. a list of links is not good practice on TSE because they can become broken over time and make your answer invalid.